# PDO return single result, how to return different record from 1 column multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a custom Sitemap from my database and stuck with following Issue

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy="product-cat" || taxonomy="product-brand"
```

**Query Output**

```
=========
 term_id
=========
|  365   |
|  369   |
|  370   |
```

It returns all term_id from my database through which I gather category slugs from another table to make sitemap URLs. Below is the code and it works fine as you can see in (sitemap output), but unfortunately I am **unable to extract next row term_id** & it shows always same **term_id** to me as a result 'Same URL'

**My Sitemap Output**

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
<loc>
http://example.com/search-page/?product-cat=mobiles-tablets 365
</loc>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://example.com/search-page/?product-cat=mobiles-tablets 365
</loc>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

**MY CODE**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$i=0;
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml.= "\n".'<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx', 'xx', 'xxx');
  $stmt[$i] = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy="product-cat" || taxonomy="product-brand"');
  $rowcount = $stmt[$i]->fetchColumn();
      for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
      {
        $sth[$i] = $db->query('SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy="product-cat" || taxonomy="product-brand"');
        $t_id[$i] = $sth[$i]->fetchColumn();
        $stmt[$i] = $db->query('SELECT taxonomy FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = '.$t_id[$i].'');
        $t_taxonomy[$i] = $stmt[$i]->fetchColumn();
        $stmt[$i] = $db->query('SELECT slug FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id = '.$t_id[$i].'');
        $t_slug[$i] = $stmt[$i]->fetchColumn();
      }
        echo $xml;
     for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)

      {

        $xml.= "\n\t\t".'<url>'."\n";
        $xml.= "\t\t\t".'<loc>'."http://example.com/search-page/?$t_taxonomy[$i]=$t_slug[$i]"."\t$t_id[$i]\t$i\t$rowcount".'</loc>';
        $xml.= "\n\t\t\t".'<changefreq>always</changefreq>';
        $xml.= "\n\t\t\t".'<priority>1.0</priority>';
        $xml.= "\n\t\t".'</url>'."\n";
      }
    ?>


<?php 
$xml.= "\n".'</urlset>';
$handle = fopen('sitemap_custom.xml','w+');
fwrite($handle,$xml);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

**What I Need?**

I want to extract next row term_id (ideal if it based on loop[0,1,2]) right now it shows me only result of **term_id=365**

Comment: why not use `$stmt->fetchAll()` ? That way you get all the query results in an array, and then you just loop over that array and execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `fetchAll()` to grab all the records. To grab a single object then you would use `Fetch()`

See Example below.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hello Kray,

Now after adding this I can see result like this

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 365
            [0] => 365
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 369
            [0] => 369
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 370
            [0] => 370
        )`

But how can I select each **term_id** using loop Here is my code

Comment: **MY CODE**

`$sth[$i] = $db->prepare("SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy='product-cat' || taxonomy='product-brand'");
        $sth[$i]->execute();
        $result[$i] = $sth[$i]->fetchAll();        
        print_r($result[$i]);`